# Treeview.SelectedNode not working properly

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to create a custom acting TreeView.  When you click a node it should toggle as selected/unselected. Currently I can select a node once by clicking it, deselect the node by clicking it again, but I am unable to select the node again via clicking unless I select another node first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TreeNode lastNode;

private void treeViewMS1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (lastNode == e.Node)
    {
        treeViewMS1.SelectedNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (lastNode == null)
        {
            treeViewMS1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
        }
        lastNode = e.Node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the BeginInvoke procedure to *delay* the action until after the mouse click event is done processing.  It's probably interfering:

```
TreeNode lastNode;
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    if (lastNode == e.Node) {
      treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
      lastNode = null;
    } else {
      if (lastNode == null) {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
      }
      lastNode = e.Node;
    }
  }));
}
```

If the Action method isn't available, you can use the MethodInvoker style:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
```

Comment: Forgive me, how do I do that?

Comment: @DanGifford How do you do what?  I posted the code.

Comment: Your code generates the following compilation error: Error 1 Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments.  Thoughts?

Comment: @DanGifford What .Net version are you using?  Updated the post with the MethodInvoker version.

Comment: I'm still getting errors with the MethodInvoker technique.

Comment: @DanGifford I can't see what you are doing.  "getting errors" doesn't tell me much.  I'm running v4.5 and the code I posted worked as-is on my machine, and the node would select and deselect on every mouse click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78938/discussion-between-dan-gifford-and-larstech).